# BigDecimal precision in Scala case class

Tags: scala, case-class, scalatra, sorm

I am using SORM as ORM in Scalatra application. I use `Create` as the `initMode` so that the tables are created automatically. I have a BigDecimal field as part of a case class, as below:

```
case class Invoice(invoiceId: String, invoiceAmount: BigDecimal)
```

There are 2 questions for which I am looking for the answers (might be it is just one answer):

1. How to set the precision of BigDecimal field?
2. How to set the precision of database column for invoiceAmount?

Is `unboxed tagged types` the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Tagged` types is the only way out to have default precision for BigDecimal in case class.
2. `SORM` by default uses `DECIMAL(65,30)` as the column's datatype for Decimal types. Which means you cannot set the precision of the database column unless you create the tables yourself, or customize `StdCreateTable.scala` to handle that appropriately.